# WCF modify endpoint address based on operation method name

Tags: .net, json, wcf, windows-runtime, portable-class-library

I am attempting to port a .net SDK over to a .net PCL library. I am building a Json binding since PCL does not have support for a `WebHttpBinding`. I have got most of it done, but am stuck trying to find where I can modify the `ServiceEndPoint` based on each operation contract.

For example...

```
/SomeService.svc
```

Say there are two methods

```
SomeMethod1
SomeMethod2
```

and I need to append some additional information at the end of each endpoint for each specific method..

```
/SomeService.svc/SomeMethod1 for SomeMethod1
```

and

```
/SomeService.svc/SomeMethod2 for SomeMethod2
```

The `WebHttpBinding` does this all transparently so I am trying to reproduce that same behavior.

I had a feeling maybe I needed to do it with a behavior, implementing `IEndpointBehavior` however I can't seem to find how to modify the `ServiceEndpoint` for each operation available in the service. The `ApplyClientBehavior` appears to be a run-once operation.

Portable class library does not have a `WebHttp` behavior that can be used

PCL Targets: .net 4.5 and Windows 8.1 (and later Xamarin)

If I manually set the `endpoint.Address`, my service communicates just fine, but only for one method.

I know this is possible as the `WebHttpBinding` does this.

`Referencesource.microsoft.com` is great, but following it is very challenging, and the PCLs don't support half of the objects that the .net BCLs have. We are forced to build this on our own.

Ideas are greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I found that if I turn on ManualAddressing in the custom behavior and set the message.Headers.To property to the endpoint + path, I can accomplish this.  I did this within the IClientMessageInspector - Is this the correct place to make this modification?

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        var action = CustomHelper.GetMethodName(request.ToString());

        request.Headers.To = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", channel.Via, action));

        return null;
    }
```

Any other way to get access to the actual ClientOperation being executed?  I needed the Method name to append.   I started building my own Message, where I may be able to append this operation to a property on it.   That may be a better spot.

I have a feeling that I can adjust this Message.Headers.To object in a different spot. Ideas?